# How can I add two CSS heights of different divs and make that the height to another div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have three divs, 1 floated left and the other two floated right (they're stacked).

I'm trying to combine the height of the two on the right and apply that height to the one on the left.

This is what I have, with no luck

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
   var slw = $('div.2').height();
   var lw = $('div.3').height();
   var result = slw += lw;
   $('div.1').css({
      'height':  result + 'px'
   });
});
```

TIA

Comment: Try result = slw + lw;.  Also make sure you're doing this in an onload or $(function() {});.

Comment: This MAY be able to helo: https://github.com/mattbanks/jQuery.equalHeights

Comment: @myninjaname I updated my code in my original post. FWIW, I did try your suggestion and it was a no go.

Comment: In jsfiddle, this worked when wrapped in $(function() {});; but not $(window).bind("load", function() {});. **when your selectors were .widget_e_newsletter_subscribe and .Testimonials_Widget_Widget)

Comment: Post HTML with your question - that would help with a proper solution. The `+=` is not the root cause to your issue; however, it does have an unwanted side effect that it modifies the `slw` variable.

Comment: @myninjaname wrapping it in the `$(function(){});` fixed the issue. if you want to add that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code within $(function() {}) rather than $(window).bind("load", function() {}):

```
$(function() {
   var slw = $('div.2').height();
   var lw = $('div.3').height();
   var result = slw += lw;
   $('div.1').css({
      'height':  result + 'px'
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of working code that does what you wanted:

http://jsfiddle.net/AjHrZ/

Your selectors are most likely wrong "div.1" is a div with classname 1.

However, you cannot have a class name that starts with a number (see [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)).

If "div.1" is an id, then you should prefix it with hash `#` like `$('#div.1')` - but you really should have posted the HTML along with your question.

Comment: I used the selectors in my example just for the purpose of deciphering which div i was referencing. They each have their own unique name.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the code you posted except for the misuse of a classname that starts with a number - so there must be something else wrong with your specific code. You may want to consider posting the real JS code and snippets of real HTML with the proper names.

Comment: while the example you posted wasn't my direct solution, it did help me with understanding jquery functions a little better...here's an upvote for you.